# How can I change the value of a button only for a short period of time

Tags: jquery

I have a button that has a value = "copy". When the button is clicked it uses the following function to construct an anchor link.
The url get's constructed and also get's copied to clipboard.
I am able to change the value of the button from "Copy" to "Copied!".
In order to simplify things I want the "Copied!" value to only be changed for a short period of time. Is it possible to create a setTimeout or fadeOut function that displays "Copied!" only for let's say 3 seconds and then it reverts to the original value?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  $(this).val('Copied!');
  var url = 'https://.....';
  var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
  var newID = url +'#'+ thisId;
  var  newIdCopied = $('<input>').val(newID).appendTo('body').select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
});
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` with a function callback that sets it back.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer above I managed to make it work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  $(this).val('Copied!');
  var url = 'https://.....';
  var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
  var newID = url +'#'+ thisId;
  var  newIdCopied = $('<input>').val(newID).appendTo('body').select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.val('Copied!');
  setTimeout(function() { 
  $this.val('Copy');
    }, 2000);
});
```